# fast fourier transform apply window and overlap

Tags: signal-processing, fft

This may be a naive question, but I didn't find exact details in searching.

In FFT with window overlapping, after we've applied window functions to sequences of data set with overlapping and got the FFT results, how do we combine those FFT results for overlapping sequence?

Do we just add them together, treating those frequency domain results as non-overlapping parts?

Are magnitudes of these results in complex numbers frequency magnitudes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each FFT you typically calculate the magnitude of each complex output bin - this gives you a spectrum (magnitude versus frequency) for one window. The sequence of magnitude spectra for all time windows is effectively a 3D data set or graph - magnitude versus frequency versus time - which is typically plotted as a a spectrogram, waterfall or time varying 2D spectrum.

In the specific case where the data is statistically stationary and you just want to reduce the variance you can average the successive magnitude spectra - this is called ensemble averaging. Normally though for time-varying signals such as speech or music you would not want to do this.